# Can this Boolean expression be simplified?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the Boolean expression

!B((!A.!C) + (!C.D) + (A.C.!D))

Can this be simplified using factorization or race hazard and redundancy, or is it in its simplest form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the basic gates it can not be simplified any further.

My solution was:

```
!B( (!CD) + !D(AC + !(A+C) )
```

When "exclusive or" is allowed:

```
!B( (!CD) + !D!(A xor C) )
```

Choose whatever suits you best.

By the way, [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) are a problem of a logic circuits (glitch), but they can't be used for simplification.